# How to fix error: Unexpected usage loading foreign module for monaco editor in vue-cli-3

Tags: webpack, optimization, vue-cli-3, monaco-editor

When i try to include optimization options in my vue-cli-3 project, which use monaco-editor in some pages, I get the following error in console:

```
languageFeatures.js?ff36:85 Error: Unexpected usage
    at EditorSimpleWorker.loadForeignModule (editorSimpleWorker.js?ccf6:540)
    at eval (webWorker.js?af50:54)
```

Here is my vue.config.js file:

```
const MonacoWebpackPlugin = require('monaco-editor-webpack-plugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const PurgecssPlugin = require("purgecss-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ["vuex-persist", "vuex-persistedstate"],
    configureWebpack: {
        devtool: false,
        optimization: {
            splitChunks: {
                minSize: 10000, 
                maxSize: 250000, 
            },
            nodeEnv: "production",
            minimize: true,
            minimizer: [
                new TerserPlugin({
                    extractComments: 'false',
                    parallel: true,
                }),
            ],
            removeEmptyChunks: true,
            removeAvailableModules: true,
            mergeDuplicateChunks: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new MonacoWebpackPlugin({
                languages: ['javascript', 'css', 'html', 'typescript', 'json'],
                features: ['!gotoSymbol'],
            }),
            new PurgecssPlugin({paths: glob.sync(`${PATHS.src}/**/*`, {nodir: true})}),
        ],
    }
};
```

- Monaco editor - v0.20.0
- Monaco editor webpack plugin - v1.9.0
- Vue/cli - v4.3.1

So the question is, how do I avoid to obtaining this error?

Comment: The solution was to change version of TerserPlugin to 2.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The base URL of the Monaco environment should be defined and the main worker should be imported before trying to import **editor.main.js**. You can try to resolve your issue by executing the following code before trying to load the editor.

```
(window as any).MonacoEnvironment = {
      getWorkerUrl: function (workerId, label) {
          return `data:text/javascript;charset=utf-8,${encodeURIComponent(`
              self.MonacoEnvironment = { baseUrl: '${window.location.origin}/' };
              importScripts('${window.location.origin}/vs/base/worker/workerMain.js');
          `)}`;
      }
};
```

It is also important to note that you should change the URL to where your vs files are hosted.

Answer (score 1):

You also can load web workers this way (correct path to monaco workers if it is necessary):

```
window.MonacoEnvironment = {
  getWorker: (workerId, label) => {
    if (label === 'json') {
      return new Worker(new URL('monaco-editor/esm/vs/language/json/json.worker?worker', import.meta.url));
    }
    return new Worker(new URL('monaco-editor/esm/vs/editor/editor.worker?worker', import.meta.url));
  }
};
```